# beaglebone serial port interruption

Tags: serial-port, beagleboard, uart, interruption

I need to set an interruption for the serial (uart) port in Beaglebone, in such a way that when the serial port receives any info an interruption (function) is automatically activated doing something with the received data.

I have searched methods to do so, but no success. I have worked with interruption for uart ports in microcontrollers, and I though I could do the same in Beaglebone.

Any suggestion to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you intend to use the Beaglebone processor in a "bare-metal" fashion or are you intending to use one of the Linux distributions that are available? I you intend to use Linux on the Beaglebone there are many good references to serial port programming under Linux that are available.

Comment: I am intending to use a Linux distro, and after some web search I found out that the required interruptions can be set using the  library for the serial port, without setting the registers of the processor (as in the u-controllers). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
select() or poll()
```

system call to do a polling on the *tty* file. As soon as any data arrives on the device file, you take the data and do the stuff you intend to do.

Or you can run a dedicated *thread* which continuously polls the uart and deals with the data.